# Why is it that my Instagram API request sometime return incorrect results?

Tags: instagram-api

I was playing with the Instagram API and I noticed something. I can see only myself when requesting things like likes on my own media. Also, for media that is not mine, it returns a 404:

```json
{
  "meta": {
    "error_type": "APINotFoundError",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "invalid media id"
  }
}
```

Also, for the follower list, it returns nothing, or myself only for people I've followed. Why is this so?

I have also set the right [scopes](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/) in my access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of the Instagram API's new security feature.

[Read this page](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/) to know more about. Everything can be seen in this line:

> Every new app created on the Instagram Platform starts in Sandbox mode. **Apps in this mode can use any API endpoint but are restricted to a limited number of users and media. This is great for developing and testing your app.**
>
> To go Live and fully access Instagram content, you will **need to submit your application for review and approval.** Once reviewed, you will only be able to request users the Permission Scopes for which your app was approved. Because of this, your application may not be able to use some API endpoints unless the corresponding permissions were reviewed and approved.

(Emphasis mine.)

## What does it mean?

That means that you can only see some things when your app is in sandbox mode. That will be your media and yourself.

If you didn't like a post and requested to see who liked it, you will get back no one!

## How do I get all endpoints and users?

You need your app to be reviewed. That means the Instagram team will take a look at it, and if it's valid, that will approve your review.

Read [this](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/#how-to-submit-for-permissions-review) page on how to submit your review, [this page](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/#valid-use-cases) on what's valid for review, and [this page](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/#criteria-for-review) on the criteria for the review.